# Javascript scripts slows down to nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a js script to convert images (300+ in number) to base-64.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var onderdelen, afbeeldingen;
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var container = $("#container ul");
        var lengte = container.length;
        var speed = 1000;
        dataStart = "{\"onderdelen\":[";
        dataEnd = "]}";

        convertToBase64 = function(convertImg){
            if(null == convertImg){
                return "";
            }else{              
                c.width = convertImg.width;
                c.height = convertImg.height;

                ctx=c.getContext("2d");         
                ctx.drawImage(convertImg,0,0);
                dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("data:image/png;base64,","");

                return(dataURL);
            }   

        };

        $("#output").append(dataStart);

        container.each(function(index,value){
            setTimeout( function() {

                var deze = $(value) 

                $("#output").append("{\"nr\" : \""+deze.attr("id")+"\", \"naam\" : \""+deze.attr("naam")+"\", \"cat\" : \""+deze.attr("cat")+"\"},");

                kinderen = deze.find("li");
                kinderen.each(function(i,v){

                    naam = $(this).parent().attr("id")+"_"+$(this).attr("class");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var img = $(v).find("img").get(0)
                        $("#output").append("{\"naam\": \""+ naam + "\", \"data\" : \"" + convertToBase64(img) + "\"},");
                    },i*speed);

                    $(this).hide();
                });

                console.log(index);

            }, index*speed*5);

            //if(index==100){return false;}

        });

    </script>
```

when i run this is sort shuts down at 37 (index) and if i wait long enough is will finish. Can anybody tel me how to make it run more smooth?

is there some javascriptfunction i overload, is there a form of cashe i dont no about, am i overworking the setTimeout function, am i overworking the dom, are my files to big. Any ideas.

Comment: why are you creating many timers in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't create another threads but will queue tasks in "message loop" so they will all trigger in one loop-course and hang up UI if they last too long

Use `Web workers` instead or create a `Queue` and process images one-by-one instead of running multiple timers at once